# Populating array from a command output, quotations determine elements

Tags: bash

I want to populate array from command output by preserving the quotations around elements like so:

```
$ array1=("one.1 one.2" two)
$ echo ${array1[0]}
one.1 one.2
```

But any command output is giving a different result, replicated with `echo` here:

```
$ array1=($(echo '"one.1 one.2" two'))
$ echo ${array1[0]}
"one.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be solved using `eval`:

```sh
$ eval "array1=("$(echo '"one.1 one.2" two')")"
$ echo ${array1[0]}
one.1 one.2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I thought of using `eval`, but apparently I was putting it in a wrong place, e.g. just before command sub with `echo`. That did not work.

Comment: @srakitnican Useful tip for using `eval`: you're building the string that will be executed later like it has been pasted into the script directly. If you're not sure about built string then just replace `eval` with `echo` and it will be shown.